# Vue JS component to render checkbox inputs and send back to v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

In my Vue JS project I'm trying to create a generic component to render a bunch of checkboxes onto the page. I need to send the value back to the component to attach a `v-model` on the component.

Thus far, my checkboxes all allow me to choose **true/false**, but I only want to send back one **true** value, meaning if I select 2 out of 4 checkboxes, the `v-model` on my custom component should have the value of **true**

I've rendered my checkboxes, but am struggling to get the `v-model` to work, where am I going wrong?

```html
<GroupedCheckboxes :options="editor.sources" v-model="source.isChecked" />
```

And the component is:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(checkbox, index) in options" :key="index">
      <input type="checkbox">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['options']
}
</script>
```

My `v-model` needs to retreive the value from the group, but isn't

Comment: [Using v-model on Components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components)

Comment: Ok cool, but I'm not seeing my `v-model` value change, I've outputted `source.isChecked` to the screen, and I do not see that value changing. `source` for reference is inside a `v-for`, so my grouped checkboxes are within a `v-for`, and `isChecked` is a value within a `source`

Comment: @MichalLevý as per my description, I've copied the vue example and it works, but upon changing to a checkbox, it no longer works. I need a checkbox

Answer (score 1):

**Issue 1:** `GroupedCheckboxes` doesn't implement `v-model`

For `v-model` on a component to work, the component must:

1. Receive a `value` prop 1️⃣
2. Emit an `input` event with a new value 2️⃣ *Since you want the value to be `true` only if any of the checkboxes are checked, use `Array.prototype.some()`*

**Issue 2:** `GroupedCheckboxes` doesn't implement checkbox groups

Checkbox groups must:

1. Have an initial value of type `Array` 3️⃣
2. Have the same `name` 4️⃣

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(checkbox, index) in options" :key="index">
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="myCheckboxGroup" 4️⃣
          :value="checkbox"
          v-model="myValue"
          @change="$emit('input', myValue.some(v => v))" 2️⃣
        >
        {{ checkbox }}
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: [
    'options',
    'value', 1️⃣
  ],
  data() {
    return {
      myValue: [], 3️⃣
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-checkbox-group-component-in-vue-ksygl?file=/src/components/GroupedCheckboxes.vue)